# Last Row, Last Column getting weird values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So, Ive been trying and trying to learn what the hell is going on with the values of the methods with the getLastColumn and getLastRow, somehow it is throwing some weird values since I have just filled in the first 3 column  until the row number 30 so I should get values number 3 and 30 right? But Im somehow getting some weird values, like 23 19 and so on.

```
function golpesLocos(sheet, col, origV1, newV1, origV2, newV2) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx");

  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lcol = ss.getLastColumn();
  Browser.msgBox(lrow+"       "+lcol);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).setValue("Probando");
  var rowS = 2;
  /*var d= new Date();
  var rango = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowS, lcol+1);
  var notacion = rango.getA1Notation();
  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  for (var i=1; i < lrow; i++) {
    ss.getRange(notacion).setValue("Probando "+currentTime);
    rowS++;
  }*/

}
```

I think I dont get why the hell I am getting those values? Maybe soome cache related issue? I dont quite get it.

Any thought would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Enrique Bravo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have more than one sheet in that Spreadsheet. If you call the function [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) or [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) directly to the Spreadsheet instead of a Sheet, by default it runs on the first Sheet (even if its hidden) To make sure it gets the values of the sheet you want, get the sheet before, you can use:

**[getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename):**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("{YOUR_ID}");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja1')
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
}
```

**[getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)**:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("{YOUR_ID}");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1] // Index of the sheet
  var lrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! apparently it was the non selection of the sheet. I just deleted the other sheet and it worked out wonders! Thanks!!!

Comment: You can also move the sheet you want to edit to first position, all to the left (: